# Remove the duplication of code which is exactly the same for two discrete types in F#

Tags: types, f#, docx, code-duplication

I have a discrete union WordContainer that is either a Doc of WordDocument or a Cell of WordTableCell.
For the purposes of this specific function each type has the same API in terms of functions. I am
using a match expression to determine whether the value is a Doc or a Cell and then have under each
case the same code with two different variables.

I have spent some time looking this up and reading documentation to figure out how
to remove the duplication. First I thought a type class would be great but those
are apparently a foreign concept to F#. Then I thought that maybe an interface
could be good, but it seemed like I needed full blown classes for those using
actual methods which greatly complicated the type hierarchy that I have right now.
Trying to leave the type wrapped and working through that did not work, didn't
expect it to but I still tried.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/f-docx/ link to repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `WordTableCell` and `WordDocument` offer similar API's, but don't share a base class or interface. This is called "duck typing".

### Solution 1: Helper functions

One way to handle this is to factor out the differences by creating your own `addParagraph` and `addTable` helper functions:

```ml
    let rec addPartUnified (part: DocumentPart) addParagraph addTable =
        match part with
        | Par paragraph ->
            for run in paragraph do
                let wordParagraph : OfficeIMO.Word.WordParagraph = addParagraph run.text
                ()
        | Img image ->
            (addParagraph "").AddImage (image.path, 100, 100, OfficeIMO.Word.WrapTextImage.Square) |> ignore
        | Tab table ->
            let wordTable : OfficeIMO.Word.WordTable = addTable (table.rows, table.cols)
            for cell in table.cells do
                for row = cell.height - 1 downto 0 do
                    for col = cell.width - 1 downto 0 do
                        wordTable.Rows[row+cell.y].Cells[col+cell.x].MergeHorizontally 1
                        wordTable.Rows[row+cell.y].Cells[col+cell.x].MergeVertically 1
                FillWordContainer (Cell wordTable.Rows[cell.y].Cells[cell.x]) cell.content
        | Lst listing ->
            let wordListing = (addParagraph "").AddList OfficeIMO.Word.WordListStyle.Bulleted
            for text in listing do
                wordListing.AddItem text |> ignore
```

You can then call the unified function like this:

```ml
    and addPart part (master: WordContainer) =
        match master with
        | Cell cell ->
            addPartUnifiied part cell.AddParagraph cell.AddTable
        | Doc document ->
            addPartUnifiied part document.AddParagraph document.AddTable
```

This is basically a poor man's typeclass.

### Solution 2: Members

Another solution that is slightly more verbose, but perhaps more extensible, is to create a unified interface on the `WordContainer` type by defining `AddParagraph` and `AddTable` members:

```ml
    type WordContainer =
    
        Doc of OfficeIMO.Word.WordDocument | Cell of OfficeIMO.Word.WordTableCell

        member master.AddParagraph(text : string) =
            match master with
            | Cell cell -> cell.AddParagraph(text)
            | Doc document -> document.AddParagraph(text)

        member master.AddTable(rows, columns) =
            match master with
            | Cell cell -> cell.AddTable(rows, columns)
            | Doc document -> document.AddTable(rows, columns)
```

You can then call them like this:

```ml
    let rec addPart (part: DocumentPart) (master: WordContainer) =
        match part with
        | Par paragraph ->
            for run in paragraph do
                let wordParagraph = master.AddParagraph run.text
                ()
        | Img image ->
            (master.AddParagraph "").AddImage (image.path, 100, 100, OfficeIMO.Word.WrapTextImage.Square) |> ignore
        | Tab table ->
            let wordTable = master.AddTable (table.rows, table.cols)
            for cell in table.cells do
                for row = cell.height - 1 downto 0 do
                    for col = cell.width - 1 downto 0 do
                        wordTable.Rows[row+cell.y].Cells[col+cell.x].MergeHorizontally 1
                        wordTable.Rows[row+cell.y].Cells[col+cell.x].MergeVertically 1
                FillWordContainer (Cell wordTable.Rows[cell.y].Cells[cell.x]) cell.content
        | Lst listing ->
            let wordListing = (master.AddParagraph "").AddList OfficeIMO.Word.WordListStyle.Bulleted
            for text in listing do
                wordListing.AddItem text |> ignore
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I think for now I will go with the first solution but I might end up using the second if things get much more complicated. It still might be good for something else.

Comment: The fix has been implemented [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/f-docx/code/ci/3aa96491ad0d265dd1fc0985b4a451f087c909db/tree/Program.fs?diff=3b801105de4a1ec238bbf4e70c3faf13f71ec99f).

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer when you have a minute.